# Redirect to another Form

Tags: 2010

I have 2 Lists. The first list is **Companies** and the second one is **Products**.

I created a workflow which starts when I create an item in the **Companies** list and the workflow job is to create an item in the **Products** list with the same company name.

For example I create a company in the companies list called "IBM" then the workflow should start and create an item in the products list and set the title column to "IBM".

Then I created a custom edit form in companies list and added a form action button. I want this form action button to be used as follows:

When I edit item in companies list for example (IBM) and when I click on this form action button it should take me to edit form in products list where its Title = IBM 
and I want to load this item using Title not ID because ID is not fixed.

Which means in another way I want when I open the edit form for any item in the first list Companies and click form action button it redirects me to the edit form in the Products list for the item whose Title(in products list) = Title (in Companies list).

Please help me how to do that